# Algorithm causes segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have built an algorithm that follows the following:

```
input n
print n
if n = 1 then STOP
if n is odd then n ←− 3n + 1
else n ←− n/2 GOTO 2
```

Whereby if `n = 22` this should print out:

```
22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Given an input n, it is possible to determine the number of numbers printed before and including the 1 is printed. For a given n this is called the cycle-length of n. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16.

Therefore I have to determine the cycle-length between and including two integers `i,j` respectively.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100
int test(int i, int j){
    int* z[MAXSIZE];
    int n = j-i;
    int *p;
    p = &j;
    int o = 0;
    while(&free){
        int k = 0;
        printf("\n%d -> %d ->> %d & %d", i, j, n, *p);
        while(&free){
        if (i == 1){
            break;
        } else if ((i % 2) != 0)
        {
            i = 3*i+1;
        } else{
            i = i/2;
        }
        k++;
    }
    (*z)[o] = k;
    o++;
    
    if (n == 1){
        break;
    }
        n--;
        i = *p-n;
    }
    size_t size = sizeof(z)/sizeof(z[0]);
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        //printf("\n RESULTS: -- %d", (*z)[i]);
        if (m < (*z)[i]){
         m = (*z)[i];
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return m;
}

int main(){
    int i=900;
    int j=1000;
    int result;
    result = test(i,j);
    printf("\n RESULT: %d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this is producing a segmentation fault which it caused my pointer deficiency, however, I cannot locate it.

UPDATE:
Based on the comments, I believe the programme now runs as intended

Comment: Local non-static array of size `10000000` is cause of segmentation fault.

Comment: on a 64 bit machine that z array ocupies 80mb, way to large for the stack. Make it dynamic (on the heap) or static

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why `while(&free)` and why not `while(1)`?

Comment: allocate memory for z on the heap

Comment: Besides the segmentation fault, what's the expected output of the program?

Comment: The [Collatz conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) has been explored more thoroughly than you will be able to do by simple ordinary means.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is just how it is with most of these algorithms! so many research and time are put into them.

Comment: If the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is true!

Comment: `z[o] = &k;` Storing the address of a stack variable is always going to end in tears...

Comment: @picchiolu good question! I updated the post as I made a minor mistake but think a mistake still persists. I'm attempting the Collatz conjecture and storing the number of cycles it takes for `i` to reach `1` from `i` between `900-1000` into a vector. However, the output for the vector produces incorrect values.

Comment: @Fe2O3 ah that was my problem! fixed this, thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @Emil11 declaring an array of pointers to ```int``` and then dereferencing the pointers without allocating memory is not a good idea.

Comment: Do you even need to store it, or do you just want to count it? [This might be useful for testing](https://oeis.org/A006577/b006577.txt).

Comment: @Emil11 the latest version of your program is still trying to access unallocated memory.

Comment: Emil11, "UPDATE: Based on the comments, I believe the programme now runs as intended" --> No.

Comment: @picchiolu Oh I see, I should use `malloc` to allocate memory to `z` then store the content of `i` into `z`?

Comment: Seriously -- what's with all those `while(&free)`?

Answer (score 1):

"producing a segmentation fault " that is  because `(*z)` is UB.
`z` is an  uninitialized array of pointers.

Comment: Yes, I’ve pointed this out in my comments but so far no reaction from the OP…

Comment: I think the fault was originally caused by `MAXSIZE`

Comment: @Emil11 What ever value `MAXSIZE` has, `(*z)` remains _undefined behavior_ (UB) as `z[0]` is not initialized/assigned when `*z` is attempted.   Why is code declaring an  array of **pointers** anyways?